# How to get the correct value from props.match.params in the child component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, token

In my ReactJS App I need to check the token received by email. In the route I define the path with :token param and I accept it in the props of child component.

```
class App extends Component {
    //...
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <Fragment>
                        //...
                        <main>
                            <div className="container">
                                <Switch>
                                    //...
                                    <Route path='/email-verify/:token' component={EmailVerify} />
                                </Switch>
                            </div>
                        </main>
                    </Fragment>
                </Router>
            </Provider >
        )
    }
}
```

And after in the child component I pass the param in action creator function. But useEffect function outputs to the console `token=xxx`instead of simple value `xxx`:

```
export function EmailVerify(props) {
      useEffect(() => {
            //emailVerify({ 'token': props.match.params.token });
            console.log(token) // 'token=xxx'
      }, [])
      return <div>{props.match.params.token}</div>
}
export default connect(null, { emailVerify })(EmailVerify);
```

**What could be the problem?**

Comment: where `match` comes from? Are you using `react-router`? Routing should come from `withRouter()`, not from the (Redux?) `connect()`. Also note that using function components you won't need those HOC any more.

Comment: See if this helps https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

Comment: Yes, I use react-router. In my connect I defined a function in [mapDispatchToProps] but in the context of this question it does not matter.

Comment: if you're using `connect()` just for `mapDispatchToProps()` (side note: not sure which Redux version you're using but you also have nice hooks with Redux) then where `match.paras.token` comes from? It's not given a value from Redux, you're not giving a value with `withRouter()` and...is it a property passed down from the container?